# Android Stretch ImageView to fill width, maintain aspect ratio, align top

Tags: android, image, android-layout

I'm trying to expand an `ImageView` that sits inside a `RelativeLayout`. I want the width to fill the parent while still maintaining the aspect ratio of the image. This sounds an awful lot like I could just use centerCrop in the XML layout file. The difference is that I do not want the image center-aligned. What I want is the image to be aligned to the top of the parent, with any excess on the bottom of the image to be cropped.

Here is the XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:background="#f00"
        android:id="@+id/skyline_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="25">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bg_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/bg_img"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is my code:

```
final RelativeLayout headerContainer = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.skyline_header);
final ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.bg_image);

ViewTreeObserver vto = headerContainer.getViewTreeObserver();

vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {

        headerContainer.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

        double imgAspectRatio = (double)iv.getMeasuredWidth() / (double)iv.getMeasuredHeight();

        int screenWidth = getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;

        Log.d("tag", Integer.toString(iv.getMeasuredWidth()));
        Log.d("tag", Integer.toString(iv.getMeasuredHeight()));
        Log.d("tag", Double.toString(imgAspectRatio));
        Log.d("tag", Integer.toString(screenWidth));

        int newHeight = (int) ((double)screenWidth * imgAspectRatio);

        img.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.Layout(screenWidth, newHeight));
        img.requestLayout();
    }
});
```

This code results in exactly what you would see if you just set `scaleType="fitCenter"`. It fills the height of the container, centers the image, and leaves margins on the left and right.

The output is strange. It shows that the image view has the same width as the screen:

> 1440
> 562
>   2.5622775800711746
> 1440

Hopefully this will communicate conceptually what I have right now:

[image]

I want the picture to stretch to fill the entire horizontal space (no visible red remaining) without making the swimmer look really freakishly wide (i.e. keep the aspect ratio intact). The water underneath the swimmer can be cropped as needed to maintain the first two requirements.

Comment: What's strange about output? imageview's `width` matches parent's `width` (`android:layout_width=match_parent` && no padding) and the default value of `scaleType` is `fitCenter`, I don't get what you intend to do and what you exactly expect.

Comment: Here is where I'm confused: The width of the image (as drawn) is approximately half of the screen width. My log outputs are intended to reveal the exact dimensions as drawn, which is clearly different than the screen width. While the default value of scaleType is fitCenter, the intended purpose of my code is to change the rendering of this image such that it is no longer fitCenter. As I said in my post, my objective is closer to centerCrop except aligned to the top rather than the center.

Comment: So I'd rather not get bogged down on log outputs but instead focus on why my code isn't accomplishing the redraw of the image in the way I am hoping.

Comment: You could try setting `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` for imageview

Comment: @Alex unlike your assumption, width of imageview is not same as the drawn part, log drawable dimensions and you'll find it out yourself.

Comment: @ebyt - that was actually the first thing I attempted. I was hoping that a simple match_parent on the width and wrap_content on the height would be the solution, but no such luck.

Comment: @Alex you want to crop the image from top, not center (cropCenter) right ?

Comment: Yes. The part of the image that goes away is supposed to be the water under the swimmer. You'll still see the top of the swimmer's head and his arms will be at the edges of the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, fortunately android API provides another `scaleType`: `matrix`, So you are free to show parts of image you want, add these lines of code to `onCreate` method of the `Activity` :

```
    final ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);
    iv.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            int viewWidth = iv.getMeasuredWidth();
            int viewHeight = iv.getMeasuredHeight();
            Drawable src = iv.getDrawable();
            if (src != null) {
                int srcWidth = src.getIntrinsicWidth();
                int srcHeight = src.getIntrinsicHeight();
                float wRatio = (float) viewWidth / srcWidth;
                float hRatio = (float) viewHeight / srcHeight;
                float scaleFactor = Math.max(wRatio, hRatio);
                float hTranslate = (viewWidth - scaleFactor * srcWidth) / 2;
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.setScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
                matrix.postTranslate(hTranslate, 0);
                iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
                iv.setImageMatrix(matrix);

                Log.i("test", "srcWidth: " + srcWidth);
                Log.i("test", "srcHeight: " + srcHeight);
                Log.i("test", "viewWidth: " + viewWidth);
                Log.i("test", "viewHeight: " + viewHeight);
                Log.i("test", "wRatio: " + wRatio);
                Log.i("test", "hRatio: " + hRatio);
                Log.i("test", "scaleFactor: " + scaleFactor);
                Log.i("test", "hTranslate: " + hTranslate);
            }
            iv.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
```

first you register an `OnGlobalLayoutListener` so you will access the dimension of the view in the right time (I believe you already know it), then you compute `wRatio`(width ratio) and `hRatio`(height ratio) using provided parameters and choose the bigger one as the `scaleFactor` (so you make sure that `drawable` covers whole of the view), Also you need to align `drawable` center horizontally (that's the role `hTranslate` plays), finally create the matrix and we're there!

**Original image :**

[image]

**centerCrop result:**

[image]

**topCrop result (what we did by code)**

[image]

Comment: Yes, I knew about matrix, but hadn't attempted to use it as a solution to this problem. Thank you very much. This is an excellent solution!